# Android ADB Linux problem

Tags: android, linux, shell, strace

I'm trying to test Strace tool in Android Real device but I can't get any information from it.
I was trying the following command but the device still tell me "permission denied".

```
 '$' adb shell su strace -p <PID_number>
```

I tried to split the commands and make it in two times in this way and it works

```
 '$' adb shell su
 '#' strace -p <PID_number>
```

I tried to put the previous code in this way, to make it secuentially but still is not working:

```
 '$' adb shell su  && strace -p <PID_number>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys finally I found the answer and I want to share it with you :)

As you can see in the previous picture I was using `shell:shell` in strace instead of `root:shell` so I changed using the following command:

```
'#' chown root strace
```

After that I give permission to execute with this one:

```
'#' chmod 4777 strace
```

So now, I have strace in this way and I don't see anymore ""ptrace attach failed: Operation not permitted" message

```
-rwsrwxrwx root shell 134508 2011-03-1 16:41 strace
```

Thank you to everybody helping me finding the solution ;)

Comment: also copy it to /data and not to /sdcard/Download

Answer (score 1):

Non-rooted phones won't let you run the `su` command. Besides, `strace` is not a default binary in android. In order for this command to work you will need a rooted device and an ARM binary of `strace`.

Comment: @Rodrigo Chiossi: I have both of them, rooted device and ARM binary of Strace.

If I make it manually the second code works perfectly, but I want to do it with a perl script. The main problem is that I don't know how to make 2 steps in the same promt, I mean first code `'$' adb shell su` and in the result promt of that command  `'#' strace -p <PID_number>`. I the emulator works fine.

Comment: @Martin Solac: I've just tested with my rooted Galaxy S and had no problem executing the command. I pulled the strace binary from gingerbread emulator and pushed to the phone. `adb shell` and then `strace -p <PID_number>` works flawlessly. In my device I don't need `su` as I'm already root when I log to adb shell.

Comment: @Rodrigo Chiossi:
With this command I get this result: 
C: adb shell strace -p pid    R: ptrace attach failed: Operation not permitted    

With another command i get this one:
C: adb strace shell su strace -p pid  R: permission denied

Comment: @Martin Solac: I did some further testing and I noticed that everything works fine when I try to `strace` an Application process, but sometimes I get "attach fail" when trying to run `strace` with system PIDs. But this seems to be arbitrary, if It fails, I just run it again an it works.

Comment: @Rodrigo Chiossi: I also have a Samsung Galaxy S rooted with z4root. Would you please send me the strace binary to the email?
Here is vansoft1080@hotmail.com
I will realy appreciate your collaboration because I tried many different ways but without success.
I also post a picture of the system/xbin folder with strace permissions and so on. Best regards

Comment: @Martin Solac: You can get the `strace` I'm using form here: http://www.mediafire.com/?gwoykk06rjjc5o0 . Just `adb push strace /system/xbin/` then `adb shell chmod 755 /system/xbin/strace` and then `adb shell strace -p <PID>` . Just checked again and it's working with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$ adb shell su -c strace -p <PID>
```

or set the SETUID bit on strace.